# PayPal initial payment fails but profile created anyway

Tags: paypal, laravel-5, recurring-billing

This is driving me nuts, We're using PayPal Pro, REST API for billing agreements and we charge our users a fee per month in our Laravel app.

We have set: "initial_fail_amount_action": "CANCEL" but when the payment fails it still creates the profile and as a result my users are sent an invoice.

Practically any card number with the wrong details seems to be enough to activate the profiles.

This is in Live mode, I can search the web for a dummy credit card number, use any name and location and that is enough to trigger the "sale".

I've searched everywhere for a straight answer but can't get one. I hope someone can help

Comment: Have you sorted it out eventually? This is driving us nuts!

Comment: Hey, yes- I contacted paypal and there was some issue on their end. After that initial_fail_amount_action worked